# UnresolvedAddressException - Thingsboard Gateway

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to use the Thingsboard gateway to connect to a PFC200 PLC, which is running Codesys. I can't get the Gateway OPC-UA extension to connect.

The name 'pfc200' resolves OK in a terminal (ping pfc200) and port 4840 is open, but when I start the gateway, the gateway crashes with the Java exceptions listed in the log file. (snippet below)

I'm using the debian distribution from gitub; version 1.2.1 on a 64 bit Mint VM running under virtualbox. The name 'pfc200' is listed in /etc/hosts. I added a DNS name in my server, which also failed. Note: I still haven't figured out the proper Application URI. But .. I'll open another topic for that issue.

Thanks for any help.

Snippet from /var/log/tb-gateway/tb-gateway.log:

2017-11-04 10:27:39,602 [main] INFO  o.t.g.e.opc.OpcUaServerMonitor - Initializing OPC-UA server connection to [pfc200:4840]!

2017-11-04 10:27:43,125 [main] ERROR o.t.g.e.opc.OpcUaServerMonitor - OPC-UA server connection failed!

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)

Answer (score 0):

I used the free UAExpert tools to test the URI. After successfully testing my connection there to a Raspberry Pi running Codesys as an OPC Server I then used that URI in my JSON file for the gateway. You can get this from the properties of the connection in this software. This information should get you past that part:

You can also try typing in the IP address in the URI like this:

> 2018-02-13 17:54:44,267 [main] INFO  o.t.g.e.opc.OpcUaServerMonitor - Initializing OPC-UA server connection to [192.168.1.29:4840]!